# What does this sentence mean 我是男猪脚?

Tags: meaning-in-context, internet-slang

I tried looking up online dictionary but cannot find the meaning of 男猪脚? Its literal meaning is "I am a male pig's foot" and it makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [internet slang](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%92%E8%81%94%E7%BD%91%E7%94%A8%E8%AF%AD): `猪脚` refers to `主角` (they have similar pronunciation), i.e. `protagonist` / `leading role [character]`. The original meaning of `猪脚` is `pig feet`; as @NS.X. commented, as internet slang it's usually used for playfulness, sarcasm or self-mockery.

`我是男猪脚` means *I am the leading man (main actor)*.

Related terms: `男猪` (`男主角`), `女猪` (`女主角`).

Comment: Thank you very much. Btw, do you know any site that I can search for these Chinese slang?

Comment: Here's a list on [wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E5%A4%A7%E9%99%86%E7%BD%91%E7%BB%9C%E7%94%A8%E8%AF%AD%E5%88%97%E8%A1%A8); but it doesn't include `猪脚`. Or you can just search "网络用语大全", you'll get many lists, like [this one](https://www.201980.com/juzi/liuxing/944.html).

Comment: To be frank the new slang comes out at a very fast frequency. For instance, there are lots of new words coming from Baidu Tieba or Bilibili.tv every day. Feel free to drop a question here if you couldn't find an answer from Google/Wikipedia.

Comment: it is in bkrs：猪脚 2) инт. главный персонаж (созвучно 主角) （Int. main personality)

Comment: Worth noting the purpose of using internet slang here could be playfulness, sarcasm or self-mockery.